# What does "child of reflection" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, literature

From *Venus in Furs* of Leopold von Sacher-Masoch ([full text](http://www.gutenberg.org/dirs/etext04/8vnsf10h.htm)):

> And yet a restless, always unsatisfied craving for the nudity of
>   paganism," she interrupted, "but that love, which is the highest joy,
>   which is divine simplicity itself, is not for you moderns, you
>   **children of reflection**. It works only evil in you. As soon as you wish
>   to be natural, you become common. To you nature seems something
>   hostile; you have made devils out of the smiling gods of Greece, and
>   out of me a demon. You can only exorcise and curse me, or slay
>   yourselves in bacchantic madness before my altar. ...

What does "children of reflection" mean? I'm aware that reflection has meanings like: "careful thought or consideration", "consideration of some subject matter" among others. From the context, it looks like its meaning is close to "modern" or perhaps "children of reason", but I cannot be sure.

P.S.: The original German phrase is "euch Kinder der Reflexion" (can be freely downloaded from [Feedbooks](http://www.feedbooks.com/book/3160/venus-im-pelz))

Comment: "Philosophers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary meaning in German has to do with thought so "children of reason" is almost certainly the sense the author intended. And, indeed, if you Google <"children of reason" Venus in Furs> you get translations which use that phrase.

Also note that "Kinder der Reflexion" is not a phrase invented by Leopold von Sacher-Masoch. If you do a Google search on that you get earlier 19th century writings.

Comment: I would render it prosaically something like *members of a culture prone to over-intellectualizing.*

Comment: Agreed; the sense I get from the passage is that the addressees are incapable of enjoying simple pleasures for their own sake; they have to stop and analyze things, and in so doing they destroy their enjoyment of them.